# Data type mismatch using RND()

Tags: sql, ms-access, random

I need some assistance with an SQL query.  The query is meant to return 75 random records from a table. Here is the query:

```
SELECT TOP 75 a.Number, a.Location, a.Manufacturer
FROM a
WHERE (((a.Location) = 'Columbus'))
ORDER BY Rnd(Int(Now()*Number)-Now()*Number);
```

This query works fine if I use a different city name in the `WHERE` clause.  For example if I change the `WHERE` clause to `WHERE (((a.Location) = 'Toledo'))` the query works.  However, if the city name is 'Columbus', I get data type mismatch error.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to verify the values in the `Number` column where `a.Location = 'Columbus'`... I suspect you have a non-numeric value in one of the Number columns, which is causing the type mismatch error.

You can use this to narrow it down:

```
SELECT *
FROM a
WHERE NOT ISNUMERIC(a.Number) and a.Location = 'Columbus'
```

Or better yet, exclude the location to find any possible bad values:

```
SELECT *
FROM a
WHERE NOT ISNUMERIC(a.Number)
```

Comment: After I posted the question I had the sudden "epiphony" to check the data just as you suggest, and turns out there were some records with non-numeric data in the number column.  Did some data validation and problem solved.  Thank you for the quick reply.

Comment: Why `NOT ISNUMERIC()` instead of `ISNUMERIC() = 0`? Negative logic can be very confusing IMHO. Is that really the only form allowed in Access?

Comment: My reasoning is just that evaluating it as a boolean expression is not valid in SQL Server, so anywhere that I can use the *same* syntax in multiple platforms, I do.

Comment: @AaronBertrand - you raise a valid point, and your examples will work in this case; however, after seeing the different implementations of `ISNULL` in TSQL versus Access (or `Upper` vs `UCase` and `CharIndex` vs `InStr`), I pretty much treat Access as it's own strange creature.  It is very sound advice, still, and is why I use `Coalesce` instead of `IsNull` (except in Access... <shakes fist>).

Answer (score 0):

Run this query:

```
SELECT a.Number, a.Location, a.Manufacturer
FROM a
WHERE (((a.Location) = 'Columbus'))
```

Once the query has run, sort it by a.Number; first ascending and then decending.  My bet is one of the records has a blank value in that field, or a value that is not a number, and that record will rise to the top of the query when you sort it.  Any value that is NOT a number in this field will cause the data type mismatch when you try to calculate the random number.